# Efficiently pass (and empty) vectors to object's constructor with move

Tags: c++, vector, move

I'm trying to efficiently pass a big vector to an object constructor, then empty it and finally re-use it. I wrote this solution:

```
template<typename T>
struct vect_obj{
    vect_obj(vector<T> &&v) : v(move(v)) {}
    vector<T> v;
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(10,1);
    //v.size()=10
    vect_obj<int> v_o (move(v));
    //v.size()=0
    v.push_back(10);
    //v.size()=1
}
```

But:

1. Even if it works, I'm not sure if it's a good practice/correct way.
2. Not sure if it's efficient (reason why I'm using move).

Comment: As soon as you `move(v)` you can no longer `v.push_back(10);` because you just relinquished ownership of that vector to `vect_obj`, so `v` is now garbage.

Comment: @CoryKramer: `v` is not garbage. It's valid but unspecified.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for your answer. I don't understand the "unspecified" state: it isn't `NULL` (in fact I can `push_back`) but I don't understand what happens to `v` after `move`

Comment: Define "valid", @NicolBolas? moved-from objects must be destructible. And I think that, in some cases, they must be assignable. But I don't think there is a requirement that `push_back` be callable (before assigning)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: No, you can't call `push_back`, as this requires it to be in a specific state (like containing things). But you can call functions that don't require it to be in a state, like `clear`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry, but if I've understood correctly, you're saying that `v.push_back` will crash the program...Which actually doesn't (tested here http://goo.gl/X6px2V)

Comment: @justHelloWorld, I think the short answer is *"just don't use an object after calling `move` on them. They're none of your business any more."*  Can you say more about the real problem you're working on. Why do you want to 'reuse' an object after calling 'move' on it?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm using it as buffer. When a certain number of elements are inserted, a `message` object is created: I pass `move(v)` to `message`'s constructor (so now `v`) is empty and the process is repeated.

Comment: @justHelloWorld: I didn't say it would *crash* anything. "Undefined behavior" includes the possibility of it working fine. That's why it's so pernicious; because it might work today, and fail tomorrow. You need to reset the vector to a known state, and calling `clear` has no preconditions.

Comment: Use `swap` instead. `vect_obj<int> v_o; v_o.swap(v);`. It's a clearer way to do what you want. Remember, `move` doesn't mean that the vector *will* be emptied. It just gives *permission* to the compiler to modify the source vector. It might even be very slow. But `slow` is fast, easy-to-read, and doesn't require c++11.